# "Float" object not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I have looked all over, and have not found my answer.

What I am trying to do is create a list of every longitude from 71.42 W to 70.87 W, and every latitude from 42.19 N to 42.54 N for every 1/100th of a latitude/longitude.

> So, kind of like:
>
> ```
> (42.19, -71.42)
>
> (42.19, -71.43)
>
> (42.19, -71.44)
> ```
>
> **...**
>
> ```
> (42.20, -71.42)
>
> (42.20, -71.43)
> ```
>
> etc.,

My code looks like this so far:

```
latlong = [(42.19, -71.42)]

while latlong[-1][0] < 42.54:
    latlong.append(latlong[-1][0] + 1)

print(latlong)
```

The problem is that when I try this code, (which currently is only supposed to do longitude,) I get a `TypeError: 'Float' object is not subscriptable.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: ANSWERED! Thanks, CoryCramer

Comment: After the first iteration, `latlong` is now `[(42.19, -71.42), 43.19]`, therefore you cannot do `latlong[-1][0]` a second time.

Comment: You would need to add 0.01, not 1, at each step, but you're going to run into floating-point precision issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are shooting for, you want a grid with bounded latitudes and longitudes? Then you could do something like

```
import itertools
longs = [-i / 100.0 for i in range(7087, 7142)]
lats = [i / 100.0 for i in range(4219, 4254)]
latlong = list(itertools.product(lats, longs))
```

Output

```
[(42.19, -70.87), (42.19, -70.88), (42.19, -70.89), ...
 ...
 (42.28, -70.87), (42.28, -70.88), (42.28, -70.89), ...
 ...
 ... (42.53, -71.39), (42.53, -71.4), (42.53, -71.41)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The last item in `latlong` is a float; floats are not subscriptable. However, your question is unclear.

If your question is "Why isn't a float subscriptable?" then I would ask what you think subscripting a float should do.

If your question is "Why does it think I'm trying to subscript a float?" then the answer is that you're looking at the last item of latlong, which is now a float, because you appended one; perhaps you meant to append (latlong[-1][0]+1, latlong[-1][1]) instead.

If your question is "How could I better approach this problem?" then I'd advise a list comprehension, one of python's great strengths. Observe what this does:

```
latLongList = [(lat/10., long/10.) for lat in range(128,135) for long in range(237,243)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 nested loops.

```
latlong = []

for lat in range(4219, 4254 + 1):
    for lng in range(-7142, -7087 + 1):
        latlong.append((lat*0.01, lng*0.01))
```

I'm using whole numbers and then multiplying them by 0.01, because the `range` function only accepts whole numbers.

Output:

```
(42.19, -71.42)
(42.19, -71.41)
(42.19, -71.4)
(42.19, -71.39)
(42.19, -71.38)
...
(42.54, -70.9)
(42.54, -70.89)
(42.54, -70.88)
(42.54, -70.87)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a simple list comprehension:

```
latlong = [(lat/100, lon/100) for lat in range(4219, 4255) for lon in range(-7142, -7086)]
```

You can find more on list comprehensions (and the language in general) [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).